# Where is the google maps API loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, magento

I have a magento website that is loading a google maps container. The weird thing is that the console is giving me a warning that says

```
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys 
 maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/29/2/util.js:220
```

but the map is still loading. How is it possible?
I'm asking because I want to load google maps on another page in the same website but I seem not to do it. It is still giving me the same error.

So I'm wandering where is this util.js file is loaded exactly on the website? If I find it I can provide it with the key and maybe load it on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used google map functionality in magento.

I have loaded MAP in .PHTML file using below API & My KEY.

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo $this->getGoogleApiKey(); ?>&libraries=places&callback=init">
```

API Key : This Key you will find from your google account. For find key click on below link and login with your gmail credentails.

For Reference Please visit below links it will help you.
 - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

May be Above things will help you.!

Comment: Thank you!! Indeed it was in head.phtml file